# Add the attribute to specific XML tag C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have XML like below

```
        <RESPONSE>
            <DATA id="1"/>
            <DATA id="2"/>
            <DATA id="3"/>
            <DATA id="4"/>
        </RESPONSE>
```

How to add the attribute `value = 200` where the `DATA id =2` .

Finally I am looking for XML like below

```
        <RESPONSE>
            <DATA id="1"/>
            <DATA id="2" value = "200"/>
            <DATA id="3"/>
            <DATA id="4"/>
        </RESPONSE>
```

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: @mmushtaq I tried this code to get that tag first

var target = doc1.Elements("RESPONSE")
                    .Where(e => e.Attributes("id").FirstOrDefault().Value == "2");

Comment: `XmlAttribute attr = doc.CreateAttribute("Value");  attr.Value = "2"; var target = doc1.Elements("RESPONSE") .Where(e => e.Attributes("id").Value=="2").FirstOrDefault(); target .SetAttributeNode(attr);` .. Use this code, hope so it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try Below code,

```
        string testData = @" <RESPONSE>
                    <DATA id=""1""/>
                    <DATA id = ""2""/> 
                    <DATA id = ""3""/>  
                    <DATA id = ""4""/>   
                </RESPONSE>";

        XDocument xdc = XDocument.Parse(testData);
        var elementes = xdc.Descendants("DATA")
            .Where(e => e.Attribute("id") != null ? e.Attribute("id").Value == "2" : false);

        foreach (XElement element in elementes)
        {
            XAttribute attribute = new XAttribute("value", "200");
            element.Add(attribute);
        }

        var str = xdc.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code snippet.

```
void Main()
{
    string data= @" <RESPONSE>
                    <DATA id=""1""/>
                    <DATA id = ""2""/> 
                    <DATA id = ""3""/>  
                    <DATA id = ""4""/>   
                </RESPONSE>";

    XDocument xml = XDocument.Parse(data);

    var elements = from x in xml.Descendants("DATA")
                   where  x.Attribute("id").Value == "2" 
                   select x;
    foreach (XElement element in elements)
    {
        XAttribute attribute = new XAttribute("value", "200");
        element.Add(attribute);
    }


    var str = xml.ToString();
    Console.WriteLine(str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 var xml = @"<RESPONSE>
                <DATA id=""1""/>
                <DATA id=""2""/> 
                <DATA id=""3""/>  
                <DATA id=""4""/>   
            </RESPONSE>";
        var data = XElement.Parse(xml);
        data.Elements("DATA").Where(x=>x.Attribute("id")?.Value== "2")?.FirstOrDefault()?.SetAttributeValue("value","200");
```